# Automate to instagram signup page using proxy

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i am trying to automate Instagram sign up page using proxy through selenium web driver. i don't think there is an error on my code because browser is landing on given URL and filling all the details properly ,but its not getting done.

Any help is appreciated ,thanks in advance.